# Render javascript in svg

Tags: javascript, svg

Adding js snippets to an svg file does render in the browser (Firefox), but when i convert the same file to some output formats (like png or pdf etc.) the javascript parts aren't rendered and don't show in the output files. Below is what i am trying to do (drawing a filled rectangle around a `path` shape):

```html
<svg width="793.70081" height="1122.51965" version="1.1" id="toplevel"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <rect id="rectG" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="yellow" transform="translate(100 200) scale(0.1 -0.1) "/>    
  <path id="pathG" d="M390.01 151l73 -366c43.3333 10 78.1667 31.3333 104.5 64c26.3333 32.6667 39.5 70.3333 39.5 113c0 52 -18.3333 96.8333 -55 134.5c-36.6667 37.6667 -81.3333 56.5 -134 56.5c-9.33333 0 -18.6667 -0.666667 -28 -2zM472.01 861c-5.33333 32 -10 53 -14 63
c-9.33333 20 -25 30.6667 -47 32s-45 -22.6667 -69 -72c-22.6667 -44.6667 -38.6667 -93.6667 -48 -147c-0.666667 -4 -1 -10 -1 -18c0 -22 2.5 -52 7.5 -90s9.16667 -62.3333 12.5 -73l36 33c13.3333 5.33333 35.3333 30.3333 66 75c39.3333 58 59 113.333 59 166
c0 10.6667 -0.666667 21 -2 31zM351.01 251l-27 141c-10.6667 -8 -31.6667 -29 -63 -63c-31.3333 -34 -55.3333 -61.6667 -72 -83c-66.6667 -86 -100 -164 -100 -234c0 -23.3333 3.33333 -46.6667 10 -70c10 -32.6667 34.6667 -68 74 -106
c57.3333 -54.6667 121.667 -80.6667 193 -78c23.3333 0.666667 48.6667 5.66667 76 15l-76 378c-49.3333 -6.66667 -87.3333 -30.6667 -114 -72c-20 -31.3333 -30.6667 -65.3333 -32 -102c-1.33333 -40 21 -78.3333 67 -115c39.3333 -31.3333 70.3333 -47.3333 93 -48v-10
c-29.3333 3.33333 -63.6667 19 -103 47c-52.6667 37.3333 -84 81.3333 -94 132c-3.33333 15.3333 -5 31 -5 47c0 52 16 98.6667 48 140s73.6667 68.3333 125 81zM401.01 1077c26 0.666667 51.3333 -32.6667 76 -100c21.3333 -58.6667 33.6667 -115.333 37 -170
c4 -64.6667 -5.33333 -129 -28 -193c-29.3333 -82.6667 -77.3333 -150.667 -144 -204l30 -155c18 2.66667 35.3333 4 52 4c82 0 145.667 -31 191 -93c40 -54 58.3333 -117.333 55 -190c-2.66667 -58.6667 -22 -108.167 -58 -148.5s-83.3333 -67.5 -142 -81.5l41 -229
c2 -9.33333 3 -18.6667 3 -28c0 -46 -19.8333 -86.5 -59.5 -121.5s-82.8333 -52.5 -129.5 -52.5c-43.3333 0 -82.6667 18 -118 54c-32.6667 34 -49 69 -49 105c0 30.6667 11.5 57.3333 34.5 80s49.8333 33.6667 80.5 33c28.6667 -0.666667 53.3333 -10.5 74 -29.5
s31.3333 -42.5 32 -70.5c0.666667 -29.3333 -9 -54.8333 -29 -76.5s-45 -32.5 -75 -32.5c-5.33333 0 -10.6667 0.333333 -16 1c32.6667 -30 64.6667 -43.3333 96 -40c20 2 44.6667 13.3333 74 34c42.6667 30.6667 64 70 64 118c0 9.33333 -1 19 -3 29l-39 218
c-18 -4 -51.3333 -6.66667 -100 -8c-94 -2.66667 -176.167 31.5 -246.5 102.5c-70.3333 71 -105.167 155.167 -104.5 252.5c0 53.3333 25 119.333 75 198c36 56.6667 82.3333 116 139 178c46 50.6667 72.3333 77.3333 79 80c-12.6667 30.6667 -25.6667 96.6667 -39 198
c-1.33333 10.6667 -2 22 -2 34c0 65.3333 14.6667 131 44 197c31.3333 70.6667 66.3333 106.333 105 107z" transform="translate(100 200) scale(0.1 -0.1) "/>

<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
var x = document.getElementById("pathG");

bb=x.getBBox();

var rect = document.getElementById("rectG");
rect.setAttribute('x', bb.x);
rect.setAttribute('y', bb.y);
rect.setAttribute('width', bb.width);
rect.setAttribute('height', bb.height);
]]></script>


</svg>
```

This shows in Firefox:

[image]

but in Inkscape, or converting the svg file to pdf or png using commandline tools like rsvg-convert or cairosvg doesn't show the rectangle. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve with that script. Set your SVG element dimensions properly and there is no reason for that script element to even exist?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The script marks the shape with a rectangle, no matter where the `path` element moves. This is needed in the application i am writing.

Comment: then at the very least make sure you're using all the right attributes and names, as per the [SVG 1.1 script element specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/script.html): there is no "text/javascript" in SVG, that's a mimetype that's used in the HTML spec. However, there _is_ "application/ecmascript". But with that said: lots of SVG utilities (quite rightly) don't have a full javascript engine embedded, so even if you write perfect SVG: check that the tools you're using support ECMAScript in SVG.

Comment: (Also, consider that if this is not dynamically generated SVG, that script element serves no purpose. The paths are fixed, no need to run code every single time the SVG runs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most SVG editors, viewers and convertors presumably do not execute JavaScript in SVG documents; they expect static XML text files. (This applies even for browser if you load such SVG as image or CSS background-image.)

If you have your SVG document displayed in browser (as document, so JS is interpreted and runs), you can then obtain resulting source code from [web console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/The_command_line_interpreter) using

`copy(document.documentElement.outerHTML)`

command: it should place SVGs source even with elements and attributes generated by JS. (It will include `<script>` tags as well, but since they are not needed anymore because their outcome is already present, you can safely remove them. Or you can remove them prior copying with `while(x=document.querySelector('script'))x.remove();copy(document.documentElement)`)

Comment: This works great using the console. Do you know of any ways to achieve the same result in an application outside of the browser? Is it doable from the command line for instance?

Comment: I think the easiest way is perhaps to let the console calculate the x y width heights of rects for each Glyph and then save them in the application.

Comment: The only option that comes to mind is to try headless browser - that would satisfy the "console" part but is still full-featured browser.  It is quite widely used for producing PDF from HTML and automate browser related tasks, but generally it should be capable to do anything normal browser can; hopefully there is no gotcha in processing SVG.